# Google maps api v2 android blank map in other country

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

i'm from venezuela, and i develop an application using google map api v2 for android, my app works well here, but a friend in spain run the app and the map have a blank screen. it's shows the indicators for zoom and current location, so the map is running, but it doesn't show the position on the map and the map itself.

Comment: Ask this friend to try running the Google Maps app on their device. If that too has a problem, then the issue probably comes from the device itself or its ability to reach the Google Maps servers.

Comment: He did it. And the map still blank!. I think is something about permissions but the application it's ok on my cell phone.

Comment: If you are saying that his Google Maps app is coming up blank, then the problem lies with his device or its ability to reach the Google Maps servers.

Comment: It isn't an internet problem.  Because the app use geolocation and it works well. The app connect to a web service too and everything is ok.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you the first time.  His Google maps works fine. But the map on the application I'm developing its blank

Comment: If his Google Maps works fine, and it is the exact same app that you and he are using... I have no idea how that would occur. A permission problem, for example, should fail consistently, regardless of country where the app is running.

Comment: I have the same problem now… :c

Comment: In my case, maps did work again after reinstall